# discord.py not matching with ==, even when manually checking

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot that writes to a file object, and deletes a message, when a specific message, '!bypass', is sent by a specific user. However, the following code will not run if that user sends said message. EDIT: This is my full on_message:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Check if the message is in the specified channel and starts with "GG"
    print(f'content: {message.content}, channelid: {message.channel.id}, author: {message.author.id}')
    if (message.channel.id == 978672833033023488 or 'levels' in message.channel.name) and message.content.startswith('GG'):
        # Extract player and level information from the message
        
        level = await handlers.get_level_from_message(message=message.content)
        await handlers.give_role_from_level(user=message.mentions[0], level=level, levelsdict=levelsroles, roles=message.guild.roles)
        # send dm
        await handlers.send_level_dm(user=message.mentions[0], level=level, guild=message.guild)
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    #if message.channel.id == 1174161702032523365:
        #await message.add_reaction('\U0001F480')
        #print('Added skull reaction to message in #announcements.')
    if message.channel.id == 1177012537410203678:
        try:
            msg_int = int(message.content)
        except: return
        if lastsender.read() != '' and str(message.author.id) == lastsender.read(): # if they sent the last number
                await message.channel.send('<@'+str(message.author.id)+'> thought that counting twice was allowed')
                await message.delete()
                lastsender.write('')
                numberfile.write('0')
                
        elif msg_int == handlers.get_next_number(numberfile.read()) and str(message.author.id) != lastsender.read(): # if the number is right, and they are not the last sender
            numberfile.write(msg_int)
            await message.add_reaction('✅')
            lastsender.write(message.author.id)
                
        elif msg_int != handlers.get_next_number(numberfile.read()) and str(message.author.id) == lastsender.read(): # if number is wrong, and they sent twice
            numberfile.write('0')
            lastsender.write('')
            await message.channel.send('<@'+str(message.author.id)+'> thought that counting twice was allowed, and the next number was '+str(msg_int))
            await message.delete()
        
        elif msg_int != handlers.get_next_number(numberfile.read()) and str(message.author.id) != lastsender.read(): # if the number is wrong, and they are not the last sender
            await message.channel.send('<@'+str(message.author.id)+'> thought the next number was '+message.content)
            await message.delete()
            numberfile.write('0')
            lastsender.write('')
    if (int(message.author.id) == 845332948524859412) and (message.content == '!bypass'):
        print('bypassing')
        await message.delete()
        lastsender.write('')
```

I attempted to run code every time a certain discord user sends a certain message. This did not happen, and my debug output was not printed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add print statements to debug and see what values are being compared, whether the condition is not being met or if there's an unexpected value.

For example:

```
print(f"Author ID: {message.author.id}")
print(f"Message Content: {message.content}")
```

Make sure that the user ID `845332948524859412` is an integer. If it's stored as a string or any other type, you might need to convert it to an integer for the comparison.

Comment: Even using int(message.author.id), I still get the same output. I already have the message info being printed to the console, and it matches the values in the if statement.

Comment: Try to create a test environment to debug the code without affecting the actual server and to test the bot's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to try:

Check Bot Permissions - Ensure it has necessary permissions to read messages and manage messages. If it doesn't it won't be able to use message.delete().

For lastsender.write(''), ensure that lastsender is a valid file object and open for writing.An error with lastsender.write('') can prevent print('bypassing') statement from executing.

Might seem obvious, but make sure your bot is online and connected to the Discord servers.

Ensure the snippet is placed in the correct part of your bot's code, where it can intercept and process messages. Typically, inside an event listener for message events.

Since you're using await, ensure that this code is inside an async function. Discord.py library relies on Python's asyncio, so proper asynchronous coding practices are necessary.

Discord.py requires you to explicitly state your bot's intents (what events it should listen for). Make sure you've enabled intents for reading message content.

If after all these checks the problem still persists, you might want to share more of your bot's code.

Thanks, MC

Comment: I have already checked all of these. I will add more code.